# Obtaining the unitary matrix of a gate in analytic form in qiskit

Tags: qiskit, quantum-gate, linear-algebra

Is there any way to obtain the unitary matrix of single way in analytic form?

In numerical form, I could use a workaround like this (i.e. for an X Gate):

```
>>> from qiskit import QuantumCircuit
>>> qc = QuantumCircuit(1)
>>> qc.x(0)

>>> import qiskit.quantum_info as qi
>>> op = qi.Operator(qc)
>>> print(op.data)
array([[0.+0.j, 1.+0.j],
       [1.+0.j, 0.+0.j]])
```

But in case of an H gate, it returns this:

```
array([[ 0.70710678+0.j,  0.70710678+0.j],
       [ 0.70710678+0.j, -0.70710678+0.j]])
```

Which does not look as nice as...
$$ \begin{split}H =
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1\\
1 & -1
\end{pmatrix}\end{split}$$

Is the a way to obtain the operators in this form, from within qiskit?

Answer (score 3):

I think your best option here is to use [`array_to_latex`](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.visualization.array_to_latex.html) from `qiskit.visualization` module:

```
from qiskit.visualization import array_to_latex

u = [
    [ 0.70710678+0.j,  0.70710678+0.j],
    [ 0.70710678+0.j, -0.70710678+0.j]
]

array_to_latex(u, prefix='H=')
```